# Return Key Value Pair

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a class and I need to pass an array of key value pairs like so

```
'options' => array( 
    'option_1' => 'Option 1',
    'option_2' => 'Option 2',
    'option_3' => 'Option 3',
)
```

I am trying to extract this into a method that complies a variables and returns it like so

```
array( 'options' => $this->get_options() ); // Desired Usage

public function get_options() {

    $options = get_options(); // returns a class
    $types = array();

    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
        $options_variable = array( $option->id => $option->name );
    }

    return $options_variable;
}
```

I am getting the result of

```
array(
    array( 'option_1' => 'Option 1' ),
    array( 'option_2' => 'Option 2' ),
    array( 'option_3' => 'Option 3' ),
)
```

How can I get the return value to look like this

```
array(
    'option_1' => 'Option 1',
    'option_2' => 'Option 2',
    'option_3' => 'Option 3',
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: change `$options_variable = array( $option->id => $option->name );` to `$options_variable[$option->id] = $option->name;`

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using like `array( $option->id => $option->name );`, then the returned data will assign to `$option->id` array. For this you need to change

```
array( $option->id => $option->name );
```

to

```
$option->name;
```